# Why is TFS Rest API for fetching the Releases returning only 100 items?

Tags: api, tfs, devops, alm

This question is similar to 
[Why is TFS Rest API for fetching the TFVC changesets returning only 256 items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458479/why-is-tfs-rest-api-for-fetching-the-tfvc-changesets-returning-only-256-items/38478038#38478038)

I tried with all parameters like top, skip and more. 
is there a way to get all releases?

Comment: There seems to be a number of different, arbitrary limits in the various API calls. Querying builds appears to only return 1,000 items as another example.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the documentation but I'm almost positive there is an overriding  total result count limit which forces you to use paged calls to get all the data.

Comment: I tried that too. Could you please get me the sample code